# tidyr split a column with character and numerical values into two separate columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data set which has an `offense` column which has the `offense` description and its associated offense `code`. The offense code is sometimes entirely in `numeric` and sometimes a combination of `numeric` and `character`.

How can I split this column into two different columns one for the `offense code` and one for `offense description` using `tidyr` in `R`?

Example data column:

```
Crime
123 Crime Description A
345 Crime Description B
678 Crime Description C
91011 Crime Description D
678(a)(1) Crime Description E
345(a)(32)(i) Crime Description F
143(a)(16) Crime Description G 
678.08(a) Crime Description H
976.D1 Crime Description I
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sub` here:

```r
Crime$offense_code <- sub("^(\\d+(?:\\.\\w+)?(?:\\(.*?\\))*) .*$", "\\1", Crime$data)
Crime$offense_desc <- sub("^\\d+(?:\\.\\w+)?(?:\\(.*?\\))* (.*)$", "\\1", Crime$data)
Crime

                               data  offense_code        offense_desc
1           123 Crime Description A           123 Crime Description A
2           345 Crime Description B           345 Crime Description B
3           678 Crime Description C           678 Crime Description C
4         91011 Crime Description D         91011 Crime Description D
5     678(a)(1) Crime Description E     678(a)(1) Crime Description E
6 345(a)(32)(i) Crime Description F 345(a)(32)(i) Crime Description F
7    143(a)(16) Crime Description G    143(a)(16) Crime Description G
8     678.08(a) Crime Description H     678.08(a) Crime Description H
9        976.D1 Crime Description I        976.D1 Crime Description I
```

The general regex used here says to match:

```regex
^               from the start of the data field
\\d+            an integer
(?:\\.\\w+)?    followed by optional dot and word component
(?:\\(.*?\\))*  followed by zero or more (...) terms
[ ]             a single space
.*              then match the entire description
$               until the end of the data field
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split on the first whitespace. Using `tidyr::separate` you can use -

```
tidyr::separate(df, 'Crime', c('offense_code', 'offense_description'), 
                sep = '\\s', extra = 'merge')

#   offense_code offense_description
#1           123 Crime Description A
#2           345 Crime Description B
#3           678 Crime Description C
#4         91011 Crime Description D
#5     678(a)(1) Crime Description E
#6 345(a)(32)(i) Crime Description F
#7    143(a)(16) Crime Description G
#8     678.08(a) Crime Description H
#9        976.D1 Crime Description I
```

Add `remove = FALSE` if you want to keep the original column in the output.

Comment: Thanks Shah g, this is also works, good to know more than one method.

Answer (score 2):

Using `read.csv` from `base R`

```
read.csv(text = sub("\\s+", ",", df1$Crime), header = FALSE, col.names = c('offense_code', 'offense_description'))
   offense_code offense_description
1           123 Crime Description A
2           345 Crime Description B
3           678 Crime Description C
4         91011 Crime Description D
5     678(a)(1) Crime Description E
6 345(a)(32)(i) Crime Description F
7    143(a)(16) Crime Description G
8     678.08(a) Crime Description H
9        976.D1 Crime Description I
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Crime = c("123 Crime Description A", "345 Crime Description B", 
"678 Crime Description C", "91011 Crime Description D", "678(a)(1) Crime Description E", 
"345(a)(32)(i) Crime Description F", "143(a)(16) Crime Description G", 
"678.08(a) Crime Description H", "976.D1 Crime Description I"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```